How to set the icon used by a desktop shortcut to a specific website (via Firefox)
I'll try this another way - How do I change the icon shown in a desktop shortcut?  This is NOT an app shortcut. It is a shortcut to a web site. Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
I've just installed Ubuntu 24.04. I then used Firefox to go to a website, and dragged the lock icon in the address bar onto my desktop. The resulting shortcut works fine to get me to that web site. But how do I make the shortcut icon show my .png file? If it has to be an .ico file, I can come up with one, but again, how do I make the shortcut use it?
